# Paperclip - Can't upload a picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

**Model**

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :image
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}

    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                        content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
                        size: { in: 0..5.megabytes }


    belongs_to :user

end
```

I choose the image I want to upload, fill in the text, submit it and then I get the error message "This field [image] can't be blank" eventhough it really wasn't. Where could be the problem?

Comment: What params are you permitting in your controller & what version of Rails?

Comment: Show your form code and the hash of data being sent through the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't permit that parameter to be access, to do that
add **:image** parameter in your controller parameters require, so you can access it, something like this:

```
params.require(:pin).permit(YOUR PARAMETERS HERE, :image)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know I had to do this. It probably fixed the problem, however now if I tried to upload the image my console goes nuts, it lags my webapp for a good minute and I get this error message "has contents that are not what they are reported to be". I've never even seen this error.

Comment: That's another problem, different from what you posted, I'd suggest you to read this link (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1924).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might not have whitelisted your name of your `file_field`. I am not sure which version of Rails you are using, so I'll provide and answer for both 3 and 4.

In your view:

```
<%= form_for @pin do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

**Rails 4**

```
def create
    @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)

    if @pin.save
       # do your success calls here
    else
       # do your error calls here
    end
end

private
def pin_params
    # whitelist it here with "Strong Parameters" if you're using Rails 4
    params.require(:pin).permit(:image)
end
```

**if using Rails 3**

```
# ==== Pin.rb model ====
# whitelist it in your model with attr_accessible
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :image

    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                    content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
                    size: { in: 0..5.megabytes }

    belongs_to :user
end

#===== PinsController.rb =======
def create
    @pin = Pin.new(params[:image])

    if @pin.save
       # do your success calls here
    else
       # do your error calls here
    end
end
```